# How to access variable stored in main controller(Admin_Controller) that acces CI_controlller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

Some variables are stored in Admin_controller that extends CI_controller, that is as follows

### Admin_Controller

```
<?php
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        $adminId =  $this->session->userdata('cp_adminid');
        $roleId=$this->session->userdata('cp_roleid');
        
        $modules=$this->Adminmodel->getmodules();                   
        foreach($modules->result() as $m){
            $getmoduledtls=$this->Adminmodel->getmoduledtls($roleId, $m->moduleId);
            $add="";
            $view="";
            $edit="";
            $deleteRole="";
            foreach($getmoduledtls->result() as $n){
                $view=$getmoduledtls->num_rows()>0?$getmoduledtls->row()->view:0;
                $add=$getmoduledtls->num_rows()>0?$getmoduledtls->row()->add:0;
                $edit=$getmoduledtls->num_rows()>0?$getmoduledtls->row()->edit:0;
                $deleteRole=$getmoduledtls->num_rows()>0?$getmoduledtls->row()->deleteRole:0;
            }
        }
}
```

The Role_Controller extends this Admin_Controller

### Role_Controller

```
<?php
require APPPATH . '/controllers/admin/Admin_controller.php';

class Roles extends Admin_controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Adminmodel","",true);
    }
 public function index(){
        $adminId=$this->session->userdata('cp_adminid');
        $roles=$this->Adminmodel->getroles();
        $data['roleQ']=$roles;
        $data['title']='User Roles';            
        $data['content']=$this->load->view("admin/rolesview",$data,true);

        $permissions=$this->Adminmodel->getpermissions($adminId);
        $row = $permissions->row();
        $data['isAdmin'] = 0;
        if($row->view == 1 or $row->add == 1 or $row->edit == 1 or $row->deleteRole == 1 ){
            $data['isAdmin'] = 1;
        }   
        $headerContent = $this->load->view("admin/headerview",$data,true);
        $this->render($headerContent);

    }
}
```

Now I want to get those variables $view, $add, $edit and $deleteRole stored in Admin_Controller to Role_Controller index() function.

Comment: you need to start using libraries

Comment: i think like this $this->add

Comment: Any public variables you declare in a class will be available to any child classes. You are not declaring any public variables in a class, I only see in the constructor, Could this be your problem?